# Scipy readsav and IDL Types

Tags: python, scipy, idl-programming-language

I am trying to restore a sav file with numpy readsav. The sav file contains an array of idl objects I have defined (with my own types).

This type information is completely absent from the recarray I obtain with readsav. The dtype.name property returns an integer which seems arbitrary to me (and I don't know how to get this number in IDL).

Is there a way to get this information ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it is the heap identifier:

```
IDL> o = obj_new('IDLgrView')
IDL> print, obj_valid(o, /get_heap_identifier)
           1
```

Comment: ok, so there is no way to get the IDL type information from python ? if I have the python counterpart of the IDL type there is no way to convert them.